# Related entries: Auto-complete input instead of select/option?

Tags: add-on, ee2, control-panel, playa, relationships

The relationship feature in ExpressionEngine is fantastic, but quite difficult to manage if a relation points to a channel with hundreds of entries. In said case, the control panel's select/option form element is inadequate.

Is there a add-on that allows to set up a relation through an auto-complete text input field, while honoring the ee-native relation fieldtype?

Would the Playa plugin address this issue?

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If yes, please mark the answer correct by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Playa can solve this. It hasn't got an autocomplete function, 
but it offers **filtering-as-you-type** and **searching**:

[image]

As solution to the problem of selecting amongst hundreds of entries, this approach is **functionally aequivalent** to an autocompleting text-entry field.

Comment: Playa does include autocomplete now.

Comment: nice, seems like I'm a few versions behind then :)

Comment: The autocomplete is on the single select field, not the drop panes, so that may be why you hadn't noticed it.

Answer (score 3):

[**Playa**](http://pixelandtonic.com/playa) is what you need. It takes native entry relationships to the next level. It does have live filtering/autocomplete now. It creates a new table to store the relationships and I'm 99% sure will convert over your existing relationships when you change the fieldtype to Playa. You'll want to either confirm this with Pixel & Tonic or test on your own. Make a backup before testing obviously.

---

[image]